# How do I match words in mySQL results no matter the order they are in?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code (mySQL via PHP) that gets street names from a database:

```
SELECT id, gps, street_name 
FROM streets 
WHERE street_name 
LIKE '%".$search."%' OR '%(".$search.")%' 
ORDER BY CAST(street_name AS UNSIGNED), street_name
```

The problem is, if the street name is `Heavens Road` and somebody types `Road Heavens` it doesn't show up.

How do I match them no matter what order they are?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is, if the street name is Heavens Road and somebody types
>   Road Heavens it doesn't show up.

And there's no reason that it should. The LIKE comparator looks for the specific pattern. If you want to reverse the words in the phrase and search again you ought to do it yourself.

```
$term = "Heavens Road"
$rev = array_reverse(explode(" ", $term));

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, gps, street_name FROM streets 
WHERE street_name LIKE %:term%  OR street_name like %:rev%' ORDER BY CAST(street_name AS UNSIGNED), street_name
");

$stmt->execute(array("term"=>$term, "rev"=>$rev));
```

This will probably be slow (and your existing query isn't any faster) you might want to invest in full text search.

Answer (score 1):

As in SQL unable to search for single name try splitting the name based on spaces like i.e `Heavens Road` and appending to string i.e `('%Heavens%') OR (%Road%)` in final query.

```
SELECT id, gps, street_name 
FROM streets 
WHERE street_name 
LIKE ('%Heavens%') OR (%Road%)
ORDER BY CAST(street_name AS UNSIGNED), street_name
```

e.g if more terms are then  `LIKE (%1term%) OR (%2term%) OR (%3term%) OR (%4term%)`

Answer (score 0):

You can able to search like this,

on every search you will approx data, not exact data: like

if street name is **Heavens Road** and you have **Heavens Roadxyz, Road Heavens, ...** , if you will aplly below code, then you will get all the approx result.

SQL:

```
('%heavens%') OR (%road%)
```

attach this with your SQL Query

You can write AND query also, as per requirement

Answer (score 0):

Your case is special, which is not possible anyway,

```
function wordcombos ($words) {
        if ( count($words) <= 1 ) {
            $result = $words;
        } else {
            $result = array();
            for ( $i = 0; $i < count($words); ++$i ) {
                $firstword = $words[$i];
                $remainingwords = array();
                for ( $j = 0; $j < count($words); ++$j ) {
                    if ( $i <> $j ) $remainingwords[] = $words[$j];
                }
                $combos = wordcombos($remainingwords);
                for ( $j = 0; $j < count($combos); ++$j ) {
                    $result[] = $firstword . ' ' . $combos[$j];
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }

$search_arr = explode(" ", $search);
$temp_arr = wordcombos($search_arr);
$condition = ' street_name like ';
foreach($temp_arr as $v){
$condition .= " '%".$v."%' OR";
}
$condition = rtrim($condition,"OR");
```

And query will go

```
SELECT id, gps, street_name 
FROM streets 
WHERE $condition
ORDER BY CAST(street_name AS UNSIGNED), street_name
```

Please see reference [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/73749/generate-every-unique-combination-using-all-elements-from-array)